# Selecting more than one distinct column in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I have a table that has columns menu and product. I need to select distinct of those two columns.

In MySQL this would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT menu, product FROM basket_products;
```

Is there any way in which I can do this in Yii2 while using find() with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the distinct()   method

```
YourModel::find()->select([ 'menu', 'product'])->distinct()->all();
```

eg:

```
$myModelResult = BasketProducts::find())->select([ 'menu', 'product'])->distinct()->all();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to retrieve distinct values

```
$data = BasketProducts::find()->select(['menu, product'])->distinct()->all();
```